# Is having secondary css style sheets a bad idea?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, modularity

So I am working on a web project and everything looks good, we defined a bunch of visual elements and modularized them into separate scss files. So when building our pages, we just import the elements we wanna use and stitch them together.

The problem is, different pages may use the same element but their layout may differ. The same button on one page may float left, while on another page it may float right. The same module on one page may have 30px margin top, while on another page it has 50px margin bottom.

What I thought is to have a secondary style sheet that contains some tiny amount of layout code for each page, and this file is page specific. Sure the client now has to download another asset but it's just a few lines of css.

But is this a bad idea? How bad? And if it is indeed evil, what will be a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: That is why it accepts having multiple CSS files, to organize, but try to keep as simple as possible. In this case seems to be good to have the two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the times a website's `<body>` tag will have a class on it like...

```
<body class="about"> <!-- for the about page -->
```

or

```
<body class="home"> <!-- for the homepage -->
```

and so on. You can do something like this to target it on individual pages:

```
.button-upload {
  float: left; /* It's floated left most the time */
}

.about .button-upload {
  float: right; /* Not on the about page, though! */
}
```

Comment: Well, but then wouldn't my style sheet be bloated with unused styles all over?

Comment: If there's TONS of bloat sure, but if you have tons of bloat you're doing something wrong. Doing it this way keeps things simple and it's fewer HTTP requests. Also, are you using a CMS? Is it easy to tell the CMS "load this extra styleseheet for this, this and this page, but not this page"? If you minify your CSS most bloat won't make a big difference.

Comment: Makes sense, and mostly reminds me of how twitter bootstrap does it. I'm not a big fan of bootstrap so maybe I shouldn't just define a bunch of utility layout classes for semantics sake. And you are right if they are all just tiny bits of css files it wouldn't make a huge impact to put them all together anyways, at least not as bad as another http request.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't for mobile networks it would be arguable but the latency is a burden.

Answer (score 1):

that's why we have classes in css so you can seperate style to classes and declare the relevant classes in every page as necessary